# connecting to PostgreSQL over a network

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a pgsql server running on windows 7. I can remotely connect to it within the network using the computer name, so i know that there are no issues with config etc. I have disabled firewall. I have a static ip and have tried to connect to the database from another network but i get the error: server does not listen. What am i doing wrong? I know small amounts about ip addresses so any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance!

EDIT:
A little more information, i have set up a home network, i have two computers networked together that can both access the pgsql server that resides on one of the computers. I am based in the uk and get my internet from plusnet, config is all done on the thompson gateway. The third computer is a remote computer not on the same network, i was just testing to see whether or not i could "host" a pgsql database for several, not networked computers. Its more of a hobbiest thing really, although would be could if i could do it for work reasons too. Thanks for you help. (sorry if i sound dumb but this really isnt my subject-yet!)

Comment: 1. Can you ping the machine from that other network ? 2. Is there even properly set up routing from one network to the other ?

Comment: Did you configure your router to accept connection from outside and redirect it to your server with some NAT?

Comment: thanks for your replies, im not that great with ip addresses and servers and routers etc so most of that went over my head tbh. I have edited above, hope that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configure the pg_hba.conf file to add the line

```
host all all 192.168.0.1/24 trust
```

that IP 192.168.0.1 is just for the sake of example, you'll put there your IP
then edit the postgresql.conf to reflect these settings

```
tcpip_socket = true
```

i think this  ^^ is only required for older versions, but add it there anyway

listen_addresses='*'

by default it's localhost, put * to listen to all addresses, or just your IP to tighten up the security

Comment: i put 0.0.0.0/0 in the ip section which i think should work? and the listen addresses is *, further more the pgsql version is 9

Comment: Look, since you got static IP's, it's better to configure it to accept only the ones you need. I know, it's a hassle, but you never know when you might need this bit of security.

Comment: yeah prob will do when i get to doing it seriously. At moment its a test of doability. Thanks for your concern

Comment: no. I think im just not doing something with the ip address, it always times out no matter what i am trying to load(just tested the remote support thing that comes with the router, no avail)

Comment: so you are saying that the third computer is not in the same network, which raises the question, how does it access that network of two computers? Over the internet? In that case you need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: yeah am just getting my head round that now. Think im winning. lol Thanks for the help

Comment: yeah i have set up the router to forward all calls from range 5432- 5432 to go to the local device(my computer running pgsql) when i try to connect using the remote ip address it still says server not listening

Comment: can you access any other services on the pgsql machine? e.g. try running Apache (or any web server) and see if you can set up access to port 80. then configure the web server to port 5432 and access that via the web browser- if you can get that working, you should be able to just replace web browser and server with psql and postgres.

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine Are you absolutely **certain** you want to suggest people use the `trust` authentication method? Especially since if a person, like Daniel, decides to configure 0.0.0.0/0, they are essentially opening all the data on their system to access for anyone who can guess a valid username (for example the default `postgres`). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html