# Is there any Java or JSP web-interface for managing PostgreSQL databases?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-connection

Before when I did PHP development with an MySQL database I used phpmyadmin for managing the database. I did operations like create a new database, add a new table or a column, change datatype on a column and so on.

Now I have switched to a Ubuntu VPS and want to use Jetty or GlassFish as Java Servlet container. I will develop my websites using Java and JSP and use PostgreSQL as database.

Is there any easy way I can manage the database this way? E.g. a web-based administration interface for PostgreSQL based on Java and JSP, similar to what phpmyadmin is for PHP and MySQL?

Comment: I don't know about Java-based administration interface, but you could use pgAdmin (the official gui-administration tool of PostgreSQL), it can connect directly to the database over a network. This does require changing some settings in the configuration though (approving connections from outside of localhost). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729663/connecting-to-postgresql-over-a-network

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only one I know of is VDBC: http://bitlama.github.io/vdbc/

Although there doesn't seem to be much activity around that project

**Edit** (2015-11-21) there is also

- PostgreSQL Studio: http://www.postgresqlstudio.org/
- TeamPostgreSQL: http://www.teampostgresql.com/

Answer (score 0):

What about webmin?

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely. See the standard modules page for a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the screenshots.

[www.webmin.com](http://www.webmin.com/)

[Managing databases in a PostgreSQL server screenshot](http://www.webmin.com/screenshots/chapter36/figure1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have just found another one called JspMyAdmin 2

https://github.com/yugandhargangu/JspMyAdmin2